# ¿Existe un dominio reservado como example.com en español?

Tags: dns, iana

Para documentación en Inglés es útil tener http://example.com y http://example.org como dominios [reservados por el IANA](http://www.iana.org/domains/reserved) para escribir ejemplos. No me gusta usar los mismos en documentación en Español, para ser consistente en el uso de lenguaje.

Existe algo similar a example.com en Español? Claramente ejemplo.com y ejemplo.org no los son. Pero quizás hay algún NIC local en latino america que haya hecho un reserva de dominios similar a lo que hizo IANA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, los únicos dominios reservados para estos casos de ejemplos son:

- example.com
- example.net
- example.org

[Más información](http://www.iana.org/domains/reserved)

Adicionalmente, como se especifica en la [RFC 2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606) y la [RFC 6761](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6761), se consideran dominios de pruebas todos los terminados en `TLD`:

- .test
- .example
- .invalid
- .localhost

[Lista completa](http://www.iana.org/assignments/special-use-domain-names/special-use-domain-names.xhtml)